# How to specify Visual Studio Team Explorer collection on start-up?

Tags: visual-studio, collections, tfs, team-explorer

This is with VS and TFS 2010. I have multiple TFS servers and multiple collections. When I launch VS, it connects to the "last used" collection. If I had multiple instances of VS open, connected to different collections, whichever exits last appears to "win" as the last used collection. This is annoying.

Really what I want is multiple desktop shortcuts, each set up to force Team Explorer to connect to a specific collection at start-up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the precise solution you asked for, but I feel your pain and this is what I use.

Download and install the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx).

From a Visual Studio Command Prompt run the following command:

```
tfpt connections
```

Uncheck the '**Automatically reconnect to last server on startup**' checkbox, and close the tool.

Then create a shortcut on your desktop as follows:

```
devenv /Command Team.ConnecttoTeamFoundationServer
```

This will open the 'Connect to Team Foundation Server' dialog on startup, where you can then select a server/collection/project from the dialog. It saves the 'wait for connect', 'disconnect', 'choose server' dance.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of [Visual Studio there is this option which will automatically hide or show Team Explorer on Startup](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/170805/i-have-to-re-open-team-explorer-every-time-i-start.html):

Help -> Manage Visual Studio Performance -> Tool Windows -> Start Up

[image]

[image]

[image]